# Erro ao configurar aplicação no IIS Local (Integrated pool)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, iis

Salve pessoal,

sou novo com .net e estou com erro ao criar uma aplicação no iis local. Abaixo print do exceção e do meu pool.

Meus recursos do iis e o projeto são os mesmos de um amigo e na máquina dele funciona.

Alguém sabe o que estou fazendo de errado ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você instalou o Framework 4.5 e registrou o Framework no IIS?

Comment: Instalei sim. Registrar no IIS é no ativar ou desativar recursos do windows ? Lá não tenho a opção.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema adicionando o seguinte código no web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: o problema com isso é q se vc usa recursos do modo integrado, eles podem não funcionar e vc não vai saber o pq

Answer (score 1):

Se você não usa `impersonate` no seu site, vá até Autenticação no IIS e desabilita. Ou então tenta mudar o modo de pipeline do app pool pra clássico se o seu site estiver sendo migrado do iis 6.